# What is an efficient way to retrieve data based on all combinations of two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am dealing with a seemingly complex problem here. Unfortunately I am not an expert in SQL so I am not able to determine an efficient, general solution to this issue.

To add some context, I am working with vehicular crash data in a MySQL table. The crash table has these attributes: id, date-time, the state that it occurred in and the weather and location of the car at the time of the accident. The weather and location are numeric values and the corresponding description is given in separate tables.

Due to certain formatting issues, I have just taken screenshots of the sample tables that I am using.

**Crash Data Table**

[image: Crash Data Table]

**Weather Descriptions Table**

[image: Weather Descriptions Table]

**Crash Location Descriptions Table**

[image: Crash Location Descriptions Table]

I would like to get the number of crash cases for each combination of weather and location of the car. For example, if there are 8 weather conditions and 8 crash locations then I would like to get 64 results with the weather & location combination and the number of fatalities for that combination.

**Combination Possibilities**

[image: Combination Possibilities]

Currently I have tried doing this sequentially but it is too slow. Here is the query I am currently working with:

```
SELECT locationDescriptionTable.type as Location, 
       weatherDescirptionTable.type as AtmCond, 
       count( c.casenum ) as Cases 

FROM state AS stateTable, 
     data_all AS crashDataTable, 
     nm_location AS locationDescriptionTable, 
     atm_cond AS weatherDescirptionTable 

WHERE crashDataTable.statenum = stateTable.id AND 
      crashDataTable.nmlocat = locationDescriptionTable.id AND 
      crashDataTable.atmcond = weatherDescirptionTable.id AND 
      locationDescriptionTable.id ="crashLocationName" AND 
      weatherDescirptionTable.id ="weatherConditionName"
```

I have thought about this quite a lot, using JOINS or VIEWS to separate this out into different queries. However I am having no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Also, I am working with [user: srr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4286098/srr) on this so there might be replies from that account as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query. You may want to change the table and column name as required. The inner query is getting all possible combination from your location and weather table and the left join with Crash Data table will give you null value on the column from Crash Data table if the matching Weather_ID and Location_ID is not found. Then you can group it and get a sum of how many had null and how many didn't.

```
create table Weather(Weather_ID int, Type varchar(50));
create table Location(Location_ID int, Type varchar(50));
create table CrashData(Case_ID int, Weather_ID int, location_ID int);

insert into Weather(Weather_ID, Type)
values(1, 'Clear'), (2, 'Cloudy');

insert into Location(Location_ID, Type)
values(1, 'Intersection'), (2, 'Parking Lot');

insert into CrashData(Case_ID, Weather_ID, Location_ID)
values(1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1), (4, 2, 1);

SELECT Weather, Location, Sum(CASE WHEN Case_ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)  Number_Of_Cases
FROM (SELECT Weather.Weather_ID, Weather.Type Weather,
        Location.Location_ID, Location.Type Location
    FROM Weather, Location) Temp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CrashData
ON Temp.Weather_ID=CrashData.Weather_ID
    AND Temp.Location_ID=CrashData.Location_ID
GROUP BY Weather, Location
ORDER BY Weather, Location
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89693b/3/0

Comment: Ah this seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Surprisingly it doesn't affect performance too much (about .47 seconds to run on a table of ~4000 entires). Thanks for the help and taking the time to create this query in sqlfiddle! I'll look into this and LEFT OUTER JOIN more.